# Как правильно пишется слово "зас(е/и)рать"?

Tags: орфография

"Засерать" или "засирать"? Как правильно? Я понимаю, что вопрос довольно некультурный, но в словарях вряд ли найдешь ответ на интересующий меня вопрос.

Comment: Обычное слово. Безусловно, специфическое, разговорное. Но в художественной литературе встречается. Для колорита. Например, для понимания образа какого- нибудь героя-грубияна.Табуированная лексика. А в отношении правописания - простая орфограмма 1- го класса: правописание безударной гласной в корне. Никакого чередования.С уважением, учитель русского языка:)

Answer (score 3):

Это корни с чередованием е//и. Если есть суффикс -а-, то в корнях бер - бир, мер - мир, стел - стил пишется и, если нет суффикса -а-, то пишется е.

Answer (score 2):

Неправда: найдёте.

Большой толковый словарь
ЗАСЕРАТЬ см. Засрать.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%E7%E0%F1%3F%F0%E0%F2%FC

ЗАСРАТЬ, -сру, -срёшь; св. Грубо. Вульг.
=Запакостить. < Засерать, -аю, -аешь; нсв.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%E7%E0%F1%F0%E0%F2%FC

Answer (score 2):

Несомненно, это корень с чередованием е/и, и должен подчиняться общему принципу написания таких корней (если после корня А, в корне пишется И). Словарь Лопатина на том же http://lopatin.academic.ru/ это подтверждает. А словарь Кузнецова в данном случае как раз и делает с русским языком то, что искомое слово обозначает.

---

Но разумнее писать на форумах это слово так: "зас.р.ть", "вы зас.р.ете топик!" Тогда никто не сможет обвинить вас в излишней грубости, так как вы легко можете доказать, что имели в виду написание **засорять**, а вовсе не то, что подумал модератор.

Answer (score 0):

"Правильно" это слово никак не пишется. Особенно после принятия  очередного закона о борьбе с русским языком.

Вообще очень длинное обсуждение (с интересными ссылками) есть на Грамоте.
http://www.gramota.ru/forum/spravka/124831/

Думаю, оно самодостаточно. Если будут вопросы - прокомментирую, особенно за друга Бегемота.

А Кузнецова - ффтопку. Ну почему никто никогда не пользуется его словарем как **толковым**? Но стоит захотеть обосновать какое-то совершенно невозможное написание - он тут как тут.

Comment: Это не специально. Просто набирают в Яндексе слово - и вываливаются результаты с тем словарём впереди, в котором есть соотв. написание.

Интересно другое: по вашей ссылке на форум Грамоты я увидел сообщение редакции (вроде бы) словаря Кузнецова о признании написания -сера- ошибочным, с обещанием в ближайшее время исправить (http://www.gramota.ru/forum/spravka/124831/#mess126355). Сообщение датировано 2009 годом. Так руки и не дошли исправить? Или на dic.academic.ru не разрешают? - http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&stype=0

Comment: *Борьба с русским языком* — это сильно...))